# Customize message when tried to edit protected cell

Tags: excel, vba

Can we customize message we get from Microsoft, when user clicked on protected cell?

I have the below code that its not working, as it supposed. I want to customize a message when user clicks on protected cell or tries to type on it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Locked = True Then
    Application.Undo
    MsgBox "You must use the Data Entry Form to enter data in this cell"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I still get the default message like below[image]

Comment: How about adding a line of code similar to the following to your above macro: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "yourPasswordHere"`?

Comment: @Ralph I dont want user to edit the sheet, unless he changes the dropdown list value to yes on the first sheet. If the value is set to "No" and user tries to edit the sheet. He should get a prompt saying change the value that should be the first message prompt I am looking for,,

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being very clear: if you want the default message then you lock the sheet and thus get the above message box. If you want to create your own locking mechanism with your own message box then you unlock the sheet and `undo` everything yourself in your macro. Either way, you should note that there is no real security in Excel and that (almost) anybody - who is a bit savvy - can override these locking mechanisms. So, I wouldn't much rely on these. Anyway, if you have the choice use the implemented locking mechanisms using sheet protection and not your "custom macro code" protection